# fadeOut, fadeIn: Variable references lost

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, callback, coffeescript

I'm working on a Rails project that leans heavily on Backbone/CoffeeScript. I can't figure out why the following piece of code is causing problems!

```
switchView: (newView) ->
    myVar = 3
    debugger
    @currentView.$el.fadeOut(-> debugger)
```

At the first debugger: myVar is equal to 3.

At the second debugger: myVar is undefined.

Why can't I access myVar from the callback function?

I'm going for a fadeOut, fadeIn situation. I've done this in the past by passing the fadeIn as a success callback to the fadeOut function. Thanks for any help, and let me know if there's any more relevant code for this problem I can post.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the way closures in Javascript works. If a variable need to be in a closure, it has to be

- Either a global variable, i.e don't declare it using `var`.
- Or it should be referenced inside the closure.

Try the following snippets in Chrome Developer Console.

1. `var a = function() {var val  = 10; (function() {debugger;
   console.log('hi');})();};`
2. `a();`
3. `var a = function() {var val  = 10; (function() {debugger;
   console.log(val);})();};`
4. `a();`

Execute 1st & 2nd stmt. In 2nd stmt, it will hit the breakpoint and you can evaluate `val` to see that it is undefined. Thats because `val` is not referenced inside the closure.

Now execute 3rd & 4th stmt. In 4th stmt, once it hit the breakpoint, you can see the `val` is 10. Thats because `val` is used inside the closure in the stmt `console.log(val);`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way closures work in JavaScript. Specifically, in order to be in closure scope, the variable must be

1. undeclared (i.e. no `var myVar` in the function expression), and
2. used (i.e. the variable must be referenced inside the function expression).

By adding some simple logging which references the variable into the callback, I was able to see a value, at least on JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/qofuzefiga/1/edit?js,console

(note that I'm not a CoffeeScript guy, so forgive the ignorance of idioms)

See this answer for more details:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200)